# Check if an executable exists

Tags: lua, neovim

I want to change this VimScript to lua, but I don't know how to check if an executable exists.

```
if executable('curl')
```

In this case I can just use the executable function defined by vim. But I want to know how would I do it without using vim's function.

```
local fn = vim.fn

local function executable(ex)
    return fn.executable(ex) == 1
end
```

I can search recursively for a file with that name in the path and if it exists and is executable I return true, else I return false.

Is there an easier way to make a function that checks if the executable exists and returns a boolean?

Comment: Maybe something like this (If executable ~= nil then) if it returns something then that will return true.

Comment: You can also check if the file exists if it's on your system with a path to it using io.open

Comment: `if executable and executable('curl') then ...`

Comment: `print(io.open(path, "r") and true or false)`